# Load balancing MySQL using HAProxy: Got an error reading communication packets?

Tags: mysql, load-balancing, haproxy, connection

I've set up [load balancing MySQL slaves using HAProxy via a xinetd](http://sysbible.org/2008/12/04/having-haproxy-check-mysql-status-through-a-xinetd-script/). 2 load balancers shared a virtual IP that is managed by Pacemaker:

**`crm configure show`**:

```
node SVR120-27148.localdomain
node SVR255-53192.localdomain
primitive failover-ip ocf:heartbeat:IPaddr2 \
    params ip="192.168.5.9" cidr_netmask="32" \
    op monitor interval="5s" \
    meta is-managed="true"
primitive haproxy ocf:heartbeat:haproxy \
    params conffile="/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg" \
    op monitor interval="30s" \
    meta is-managed="true"
colocation haproxy-with-failover-ip inf: haproxy failover-ip
order haproxy-after-failover-ip inf: failover-ip haproxy
property $id="cib-bootstrap-options" \
    dc-version="1.0.12-unknown" \
    cluster-infrastructure="openais" \
    no-quorum-policy="ignore" \
    expected-quorum-votes="2" \
    stonith-enabled="false" \
    last-lrm-refresh="1342783084"
```

**`/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg`**:

```
global
    log 127.0.0.1 local1 debug
    maxconn 4096
    pidfile /var/run/haproxy.pid
    daemon

defaults
    log global
    mode tcp
    option dontlognull 
    retries 3 
    option redispatch
    maxconn 2000
    contimeout 5000
    clitimeout 50000
    srvtimeout 50000

frontend FE_mysql
    bind 192.168.5.9:3307
    default_backend BE_mysql

backend BE_mysql
    mode tcp
    balance roundrobin
    option tcpka
    option httpchk
    #server mysql1 192.168.6.47:3306 weight 1 check port 9199 inter 12000 rise 3 fall 3
    server mysql2 192.168.6.248:3306 weight 1 check port 9199 inter 12000 rise 3 fall 3
    server mysql3 192.168.6.129:3306 weight 1 check port 9199 inter 12000 rise 3 fall 3
```

My problem is most of time connecting via virtual IP, `/var/log/mysqld.log` keeps flooding with:

```
120719 12:59:46 [Warning] Aborted connection 17237 to db: 'db' user: 'user' host: '192.168.5.192' (Got an error 
reading communication packets) 
120719 12:59:49 [Warning] Aborted connection 17242 to db: 'db' user: 'user' host: '192.168.5.192' (Got an error 
reading communication packets) 
120719 12:59:52 [Warning] Aborted connection 17248 to db: 'db' user: 'user' host: '192.168.5.192' (Got an error 
reading communication packets)
```

*(connection still established)*

`192.168.5.192` is the HAProxy's IP address.

```
mysql> show global status like 'Aborted%';
+------------------+-------+
| Variable_name    | Value |
+------------------+-------+
| Aborted_clients  | 53626 |
| Aborted_connects | 400   |
+------------------+-------+
```

I don't think 128M is not enough for `max_allowed_packet`:

```
max_connections = 300
max_allowed_packet = 128M
```

`_timeout` variables:

```
mysql> show global variables like '%timeout';
+----------------------------+----------+
| Variable_name              | Value    |
+----------------------------+----------+
| connect_timeout            | 10       |
| delayed_insert_timeout     | 300      |
| innodb_lock_wait_timeout   | 60       |
| innodb_rollback_on_timeout | OFF      |
| interactive_timeout        | 3600     |
| lock_wait_timeout          | 31536000 |
| net_read_timeout           | 30       |
| net_write_timeout          | 60       |
| slave_net_timeout          | 3600     |
| wait_timeout               | 600      |
+----------------------------+----------+
```

Is there anything that can cause this? Does it relate to HAProxy?

Any thoughts?

Comment: http://www.webyog.com/blog/2009/08/10/mysql-server-has-gone-away-part-1-max_allowed_packet/

Comment: I'm not getting `Got packet bigger than...` error. Moreover, I'm setting `max_allowed_packet` to 128M.

Comment: what is 192.168.3.87? is that the ip of one of the clients?

Comment: Yes. Looking deep into the logs, I see that it also happens when connecting via 'real' IP.

Answer (score 2):

These are the reasons given in MySQL [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/communication-errors.html):

> The max_allowed_packet variable value is too small or queries require
>   more memory than you have allocated for mysqld. See Section C.5.2.10,
>   “Packet too large”.
>
> Use of Ethernet protocol with Linux, both half and full duplex. Many
>   Linux Ethernet drivers have this bug. You should test for this bug by
>   transferring a huge file using FTP between the client and server
>   machines. If a transfer goes in burst-pause-burst-pause mode, you are
>   experiencing a Linux duplex syndrome. Switch the duplex mode for both
>   your network card and hub/switch to either full duplex or to half
>   duplex and test the results to determine the best setting.
>
> A problem with the thread library that causes interrupts on reads.
>
> Badly configured TCP/IP.
>
> Faulty Ethernets, hubs, switches, cables, and so forth. This can be
>   diagnosed properly only by replacing hardware.

And, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4455542/what-to-do-about-mysql-aborted-connection-errors-error-reading-communication-pa) explains better:

> Although they could be a symptom of a larger problem, they can be
>   caused from normal (i.e. unpreventable) network issues.
>
> Even if they're on the same LAN, for a variety of reasons,
>   communication errors may occur between your application server and the
>   database. In the cases of corrupt communications or time-outs, the
>   applications and/or MySQL most likely retries and works and the
>   problem never surfaces or makes itself apparent.
>
> In my experience, the most common sources of these types of messages
>   are from the application (server) flaking out, the application not
>   terminating connections properly, or from latencies in off-site
>   replication.
>
> Quite likely they were happening before you enabled error logging on
>   the MySQL server.

Comment: so what is the solution?

Answer (score 1):

I found that increasing the timeout settings in the haproxy.cfg file solved this error for me. I spent a lot of time checking the my.cnf wait_timeout etc and realised the bottleneck was actually HAProxy.

Comment: what is your timeout values?

Answer (score 0):

check haproxy mannul

> tune.idletimer
>
> Sets the duration after which haproxy will consider that an empty buffer is
>     probably associated with an idle stream. This is used to optimally adjust
>     some packet sizes while forwarding large and small data alternatively. The
>     decision to use splice() or to send large buffers in SSL is modulated by this
>     parameter. The value is in milliseconds between 0 and 65535. A value of zero
>     means that haproxy will not try to detect idle streams. The default is 1000,
>     which seems to correctly detect end user pauses (eg: read a page before
>     clicking). There should be not reason for changing this value. Please check
>     tune.ssl.maxrecord below.

I set `tune.idletimer=60000` and restart haproxy service. and the problem happpen again. I meet the problem in haproxy 1.8.14

the old haproxy 1.5.4 is OK.

Answer (score 0):

For me the major setting I had to use/change was:

```
timeout connect 6s
timeout client  600s
timeout server  600s
```

I suspect some clients for performance purposes maintain socket connections to mysql -- in particular PHP so the only workaround is to allow them to maintain such connections for longer. I found that 600s disappeared the errors and settled with that value.

Comment: Mr. Opata, The timeout connect at 6s is the max time allowed for 'connect' to be successful.  If your instance is busy with activity, 6s is not enough time.  Default is 10 seconds.  20s would tolerate packet retries much better for your clients and still let them in on first attempt usually.  View profile, Network profile for contact info and free downloadable Utility Scripts to assist with performance tuning.  Have a GREAT 2021! Stay Safe.