# tcpdump: snaplen set to 0 but still get "Packet size limited during capture"?

Tags: networking, tcp, wireshark, tcpdump, tcp-offload-engine

Due to [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/409973/load-balancing-mysql-using-haproxy-got-an-error-reading-communication-packets) problem, I'm going to sniff some packets on the MySQL server backend to see what happens:

`# tcpdump -vv -s0 -c 100 -i bond0 tcp port 3306 and host 192.168.3.87 -w /home/quanta/3.87_aborted.pcap`

As you can see, I set snaplen to 0, but still get the message *"Packet size limited during capture"*:

```
MySQL Protocol
    Packet Length: 579
    Packet Number: 96
    text: 336
    text: 1004352
    text: 147619
    text: 336
[Packet size limited during capture: MySQL truncated]
```

The offload settings on my interface:

```
# ethtool -k bond0
Offload parameters for bond0:
Cannot get device rx csum settings: Operation not supported
rx-checksumming: off
tx-checksumming: on
scatter-gather: on
tcp segmentation offload: on
udp fragmentation offload: off
generic segmentation offload: off
generic-receive-offload: off
```

---

**`/proc/net/bonding/bond0`**:

```
Ethernet Channel Bonding Driver: v3.4.0-1 (October 7, 2008)

Bonding Mode: adaptive load balancing
Primary Slave: None
Currently Active Slave: eth1
MII Status: up
MII Polling Interval (ms): 100
Up Delay (ms): 0
Down Delay (ms): 0

Slave Interface: eth1
MII Status: up
Speed: 1000 Mbps
Duplex: full
Link Failure Count: 0
Permanent HW addr: 00:30:48:c3:20:be
```

---

**Reply to @HeatfanJohn:**

```
# ethtool -k eth1
Offload parameters for eth1:
Cannot get device udp large send offload settings: Operation not supported
rx-checksumming: on
tx-checksumming: on
scatter-gather: on
tcp segmentation offload: on
udp fragmentation offload: off
generic segmentation offload: off
generic-receive-offload: on
```

---

**Reply to @Doon:**

```
bond0     UP BROADCAST RUNNING MASTER MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
```

Sniffing with `-s 1500` also shows:

```
 41  11.371783  192.168.6.7 -> 192.168.3.87 MySQL Response OK
 42  11.371974 192.168.3.87 -> 192.168.6.7  MySQL Request Ping
 43  11.371996  192.168.6.7 -> 192.168.3.87 MySQL Response OK
 44  11.378562 192.168.3.87 -> 192.168.6.7  MySQL Request Query
 45  11.379604  192.168.6.7 -> 192.168.3.87 MySQL Response
 46  11.402431 192.168.3.87 -> 192.168.6.7  MySQL Request Query
 47  11.402992  192.168.6.7 -> 192.168.3.87 MySQL Response[Packet size limited during capture]
```

Comment: What bond mode are you using?

Comment: adaptive load balancing. updated my question.

Comment: Do you have TCP offload enabled?  I have seen very large TCP packets returned to WinPCAP when TCP offload is enabled.

Comment: Yes, TCP offload was enabled on `eth1` slave (I think by default).

Comment: What is MTU?  Have you tried doing a snaplen of MTU size? -s0 normally set it back to default length

Comment: MTU=1500. I've tried to set snaplen to MTU size but still get that message.

Comment: I would try this with segmentation offload disabled. With it enabled, it's very possible that tcpdump able to get what it is expecting.

Comment: I'm very unfamilar with bonding, but from what I can read I suspect that both of your issues might be due to jumbo frames. I think you can disable them by forcing the MTU to 1500 (http://pthree.org/2012/02/26/setup-network-interfaces-in-debian/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is in answer form, with correct wording :) I would try this with segmentation offload disabled. With it enabled, it's very possible that tcpdump isn't able to get what it is expecting.

--Matt

Answer (score 1):

Something about TCP offloading I fully comply with:
http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/toe